# WebSphere 6.1 -precompiling jsps but can't find class file until I visit the page

Tags: jsp, websphere

My understanding of pre-compiling JSPs is that the application server should create the compiled (.class file) on startup, as opposed to when a user first visits the page.

I've deployed an EAR to WebSphere 6.1, I've enabled "Precompile JavaServer Pages files" on the WebSphere console, but I cannot see the .class for the jsp on the filesystem of the application server until I first visit the page. I'm searching for the class file quite crudely by just doing:

```
find . -name "*addUser*" -print

./profiles/AppSrv01/temp/mytestqaNode01/MYTEST_QA2/Border_Community/web.war/WEB-INF/jsp/admin/countries/_addUser.class
```

from the WAS_HOME

Am I misunderstanding what pre-compilation does?

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable the flag *after* you did the deploy? I ask because the documentation mentions that you have to edit a file if you are trying to modify an already deployed webapp

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Fuweb_jspcompile.html

"You can specify the JSP compiler options on this panel only when installing or updating an application that contains Web modules. After the application is installed, you must edit the JSP engine configuration parameters of a Web module's WEB-INF/ibm-web-ext.xmi file to change its JSP compiler options."

Comment: I couldn't find a way to enable the flag on an already deployed webapp, unfortunately :-) so I had to re-deploy the app.